# Change output colour in Powershell script

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-module

I want to modify my ActiveDirectory lookup script to output a certain result in color.

The Script Imports the AD module and then prompts you to enter a username and see certain properties such as Name, E-mail Address and Employee ID.

There are a couple of properties whose color I'd like to change depending on the output.

For example if 'LockedOut' or 'PasswordExpired' is 'True', I would like the text color to be red for these particular results.

Is that possible? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the script

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

do{ 
   $username = (read-host "Please Enter Username to Lookup")

   get-aduser $username  -properties Created, Name, EmployeeID, EmailAddress, Enabled, LockedOut, LastBadPasswordAttempt, PasswordExpired, AccountExpires, LastLogonDate, Modified, LogonCount, HomeDirectory, Office, TelephoneNumber | Format-List Created, Modified, LogonCount, Name, EmailAddress, EmployeeID, Enabled, LockedOut, PasswordExpired, LastLogonDate, LastBadPasswordAttempt, HomeDirectory, Office, TelephoneNumber

   $response = Read-Host "Enter 'Y' to check another user, any other key to exit"
   Clear-Host
}
while ($response -eq "Y")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write-Host has parameters to specify foreground and backgroundcolor:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
[string[]]$getADProps=echo Created, Name, EmployeeID, EmailAddress, Enabled, LockedOut, LastBadPasswordAttempt, PasswordExpired, AccountExpires, LastLogonDate, Modified, LogonCount, HomeDirectory, Office, TelephoneNumber
[string[]]$flProps=echo Created, Modified, LogonCount, Name, EmailAddress, EmployeeID, Enabled, LockedOut, PasswordExpired, LastLogonDate, LastBadPasswordAttempt, HomeDirectory, Office, TelephoneNumber
do{ 
    $username = (read-host "Please Enter Username to Lookup")
    $adUser=Get-ADUser $username  -properties $getADProps  
    if ($adUser.'LockedOut' -or $adUser.'PasswordExpired'){
        $adUser | Format-List $flProps  | Out-String | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    else{
        $adUser | Format-List $flProps
    }
    $response = Read-Host "Enter 'Y' to check another user, any other key to exit"
    Clear-Host
}while ($response -eq "Y")
```

Comment: Thank you Dirk, unfortunately i receive the error when using your answer.

Format-List : Cannot convert System.Management.Automation.PSObject to one of the following types {System.String, System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}.
At line:11 char:30
+         $adUser | format-List <<<<  $flProps
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Format-List], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DictionaryKeyUnknownType,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatListCommand

Comment: Hi James, yes I see you are using PowerShell v2. I just tested on v3. I've made some changes to make it work on v2, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = get-aduser $username  -properties Created,Name,EmployeeID,EmailAddress,`
  Enabled,LockedOut, LastBadPasswordAttempt, PasswordExpired, AccountExpires,`
  LastLogonDate,Modified, LogonCount, HomeDirectory, Office, `
  TelephoneNumber | format-list Created,Modified, LogonCount, Name, EmailAddress,`
  EmployeeID, Enabled, LockedOut,PasswordExpired, LastLogonDate,`
  LastBadPasswordAttempt,HomeDirectory, Office,TelephoneNumber |
  out-string
write-host -foregroundcolor Red $result
```

Comment: Hi Bill, thank you for your help, it's nearly there but basically i just want the status to be a certain colour.

For example when PS returns results i would like to change the colour of individual items; I would like 'Enabled' if 'True' to be green, if 'False' to be red. so that it stands out in a more clear and concise way

Comment: In order to do that, you will need to construct your own output and combine write-host -nonewline and write-host -foregroundcolor. For example: `write-host -nonewline "Account disabled: "` then `write-host -foregroundcolor Red "True"` on the next line. You won't be able to use format-table since that's going to output an object in the current console colors.